# Map not empty, but returns null value

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am calling data from firestore like this:

```
getDoctorData() async {

    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> _snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('doctors/1/1').doc('1').get();
    
    return _snapshot.data()!;
}
```

I call the function as follows:

```
final _query = getDoctorData();
```

Since it's a Future, I decided to convert it to a simple Map:

```
var _data = {};
_query.then((value) => value.forEach((key, value) => _data[key] = value));
```

But for some reason, the data is displayed if I inspect the variable, however, if I specify the key, it returns `null`.

[image]

**UPD**

All the code looks like this:

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:doc_app/api/get_data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DocPage extends StatelessWidget {
  DocPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _query = getDoctorData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  var _data = {};
  _query.then((value) => value.forEach((key, value) => _data[key] = value));
  inspect(_data);
  inspect(_data['name']);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 124, 243),
        ),
        child: Column(
        
        ///// lots of code below
```

I'm new to dart so I googled a lot but didn't find an answer to this question.

Thanks!

Comment: I expect that you're accessing `_data` when it hasn't been initialized yet. Can you show how the code in your screenshot related to the code that you included in your question as text?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have updated the code.

Comment: I recommend you to pass the data that you need to show in the DocPage constructor, since Stateless widget are intended to only show what you pass to them as a parameter, do the fetch of that outside the widget them pass that result as a parameter of DocPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're adding the values to `_data` in an asynchronous `then` callback, your `inspect` calls run before the `_data` is actually populated.

On some environments, inspecting an object is tracked by the environment and then updated when the object is changed (this started in Chrome/WebKit, but I see it elsewhere too these days). But when you log a primitive value, that output is only written when the code executes and not updated later.

So my guess is that the output of `inspect(_data);` gets retroactively updated when it changes after the statement executed, while the `inspect(_data['name']);` only writes the value when the statement executes.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the detailed explanation.